# Display list of only product names in flutter, using woocommerce api data in json format

Tags: android, json, api, flutter, woocommerce

I am able to fetch and print the data in json format in console and I am able to display the entire body of data in list format in the flutter app. But I can't figure out how to display only a specific key and its value in list. Its a list of maps. I have removed the consumer key and secret from this code.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main(){
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: CustomHome(),
  ));
}

class CustomHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomHomeState createState() => _CustomHomeState();
}

class _CustomHomeState extends State<CustomHome> {

  List data;

  Future<String> getData() async{
    var response = await http.get('https://jbaat.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?consumer_key=&consumer_secret=');

    setState(() {
      var converted = jsonDecode(response.body);
      data = converted;
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(data);
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              child: Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text('$data'),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the response

```
 [{id: 493, name: Bas 5 Min White Half Sleeve T-Shirt, slug: bas-5-min-white-half-sleeve-t-shirt, permalink: https://www.jbaat.com/product/bas-5-min-white-half-sleeve-t-shirt/, date_created: 2019-12-14T23:39:08, date_created_gmt: 2019-12-14T18:09:08, date_modified: 2019-12-14T23:48:01, date_modified_gmt: 2019-12-14T18:18:01, type: variable, status: publish, featured: false, catalog_visibility: visible, description: , short_description: , sku: , price: 500.00, regular_price: , sale_price: , date_on_sale_from: null, date_on_sale_from_gmt: null, date_on_sale_to: null, date_on_sale_to_gmt: null, price_html: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#8377;</span>500.00</span>, on_sale: false, purchasable: true, total_sales: 0, virtual: false, downloadable: false, downloads: [], download_limit: -1, download_expiry: -1, external_url: , button_text: , tax_status: taxable, tax_class: , manage_stock: false, stock_quantity: null, stock_status: instock, backorders: no,
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what your response data look like?

Comment: I have updated the response I see in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Jbaat, I'd recommend creating a model for your response data and use the values accordingly from each item's instance. There are few online converters available which converts your json response to Dart models, here is one - https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/. Below is a quick example of what it would look like based on your response data,

```
class Items {
  final List<Items> items;

  Items({this.items});

  factory Items.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    List<Items> itemList = json.map((i) => Items.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return Items(
        items: itemList
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  ......

  Item({this.id, this.name,.....});

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Item(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name']
        ......
    );
  }
}
```

And then your `getData()` would be,

```
Future<Items> getData() async{
  var response = await http.get('https://jbaat.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?consumer_key=&consumer_secret=');

  return Items.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)).items;
}
```

You should now have `Item` list which can be used to get specific item info. You should also use `FutureBuilder` to call your `getData()` instead of calling it in `initState` to make sure data is available before building widgets like so,

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    Item item = snapshot.data[index]; //Your item
                    return Container(
                      child: Card(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(item.name),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        });
  }
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Change the type for `data` to

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>>
```

A possible implementation for your use case:

```
Map y;
var keytobesearched='name';
List<Map<String,dynamic>> x= [{'id': 493, 'name': 'Bas 5 Min White Half Sleeve T-Shirt', 'slug': 'bas-5-min-white-half-sleeve-t-shirt'}];

      x.forEach((Map<String,dynamic> ele){
        if(ele.containsKey(keytobesearched))
           y=Map.from(ele);
        // display/alter y to your liking
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would want a complete plug and play Woocommerce Sdk that handles authentication, products, customer, shipping etc for you, you can use the Woo Commerce SDK library for flutter at https://pub.dev/packages/woocommerce

```
Woocommerce myWoocommerce = WooCommerce(baseUrl: yourBaseUrl, consumerKey: yourConsumerKey, consumerSecret: consumerSecret);
```

Then simply get your lists eg:

```
WooProduct products = await myWocommerce.getProducts(); // returns the ist of products.

for (var product in products){ print(product.name)};
```